# Cannot Install Windows XP SP1

Tags: windows, windows-xp, service-pack

Have an old computer w/o SP1. When I try to download SP1 it tells me it cannot find the server. How do I get an offline version of SP1 to install? I really need to get to SP3 but I think SP1 is required prior to SP3

Answer (score 13):

If your final goal is SP3 you can [start at SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28) as it will allow you to go from no SP to SP2 directly.

Currently there is no way to install SP1 offline via public [resources from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/service-packs).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your computers' manufacturer, you may be able ask them to send you a copy of XP with SP2 already installed.

As Scott said, you don't need SP1 to get to SP3.  You can just go from XP to SP2 to SP3.

Comment: One issue with that is Windows Product Keys are tied to a specific service pack release.  You can upgrade the service pack after installation, but the original installation must be the service pack associated with the key.

Comment: "Windows Product Keys are tied to a specific service pack release." any links to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a download page for the CD image of SP3:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25129

According to the notes, you can install SP3 on Windows XP without any previous service packs.

EDIT: Information seems to conflict.  This page on MS Technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507836.aspx
says "To install SP3, your computer must meet the hardware and operating system requirements listed below. In addition, your computer must at least be running Windows XP with Service Pack 1 installed.  We recommended that you have Service Pack 2 installed before installing SP3."